# CSS - Unknown Item - Scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a site and I came around something I never, well have I have seen this item dozens of times but I never used one myself and can't recall ever hearing about what this item is called and how to create one myself.

I sorta need this item on my website. So any Tips would be very helpful.

https://snag.gy/3U5QW4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is called html range.**
To user this kind of slider, in HTML5 it has a specific tag defined.
--------------------------------------

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="100"/>
```

**For more reference you can visit this page to have a deep knowledge about it :-**

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range

  **And here some link(s) for videos that could help you to learn more about it practically.**
- https://youtu.be/YR_O0IwDb_s

> Hope this references are helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a slider or a range.

There is a HTML5 element:

```
<input id="test" type="range" min="100" max="200" step="10" />
```

- http://html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php

Examples of other third-party sliders:

- http://www.uiparade.com/skill-type/sliders/
- https://jqueryui.com/slider/
- https://semantic-ui.com/modules/slider.html

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't have to feel confused all day :) I give you the answer, but I can't click as it tells me to wait 7 minutes .